# error: ‘_gcvt_s’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, g++

I get the error `‘_gcvt_s’ was not declared in this scope`.

My code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
float lo = 144814814.1736111;

lo = floorf((lo / 1000000) * 100) / 100;

char vOut [17];
_gcvt_s(vOut,sizeof(vOut),lo,8);
cout<<vOut;
}
```

[Compile with codeblocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHHex.png)
[Compile with g++ an pi 0 w](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80W9D.png)

I tried `-std=c++11` and similar arguments but no changes.

[g++ info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCJlf.png)

Comment: [`_gcvt_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gcvt-s?view=msvc-170) is a Microsoft VC++ specific function, not a standard portable function. Typically, all non-standard and non-portable functions tend to use one or two leading underscores.

Comment: [_gcvt_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gcvt-s) appears to be Microsoft-specific, likely only available with Visual C++ compiler. In portable code, you can replace it with `sprintf_s` with a suitable format string.

Comment: That sounds like a [Microsoft-specific function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gcvt-s?view=msvc-170). Why can't you `cout << lo` directly?

Comment: I have a float number and I need to convert to char*

Comment: `std::to_string` gets you an `std::string`, which you can convert to a `char *` with `.c_str()`

Comment: For a question like this, where you believe the compiler is wrong, your question should include an argument against the compiler. In this case, you would state why you believe `_gcvt_s` should be declared in that scope -- either point out the line that declares it, specify the (standard) header that declares it, or provide an assertion that you believe `_gcvt_s` is a core language feature. For the latter (if that was the case), it would be good to link to documentation, such as a page on cppreference.com.